# How to insert an XML file into a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have tried this example in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @XMLTable TABLE (Data XML)

INSERT INTO @XMLTable
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\sample.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA

SELECT * FROM @XMLTable
```

But it executes with error saying.

> 'Cannot bulk load because the file "D:\sample.xml" could not be
>   opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.).'

Comment: When doing bulk operations the file needs to be accessible from same machine the SQL Server is on. You can either copy the file to a shared path or copy the file to the machine where SQL Server is installed and try with the updated path.

Comment: Is this a *remote* SQL Server (not on your machine)? Then the file you want to use in the `OPENROWSET` **must be** on that server machine's `D:` drive - not your own local `D:` drive....

Comment: 1. Make sure the file is on the same machine as the server 2. make sure the file is not too big. It hase a filesize limit it can open, because it has no streamreader. 3. consider using a ETL tool like Talend to load the data.

Comment: THanks.. !!! I have moved the file into the server's location and it executes correctly.

Comment: @SandaruwanH: hi, can you post that as answer and mark it as such?